# (C++) Expected '{' at end of an input error while creating std::expection class in separate files

Tags: c++

I need to create my own class that inherits from std::exception. I need to do this in separate files. I used the example provided during the lecture, the issue is it was shown in one .cpp file, and once it is split, I get an error. How should I fix it?

RzymArabException.h file: (this is where I get an error at line 11)

```
#ifndef RZYMARABEXCEPTION_H_INCLUDED
#define RZYMARABEXCEPTION_H_INCLUDED
#include <string>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

class RzymArabException: public exception {
private:
    string s;
public:
    RzymArabException(string ss) : s(ss);
    virtual ~RzymArabException() throw();
    virtual const char* what() const throw();

};

#endif // RZYMARABEXCEPTION_H_INCLUDED
```

RzymArabException.cpp:

```
#include "RzymArabException.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

RzymArabException(string ss) : s(ss) {}
virtual ~RzymArabException() throw() {}
virtual const char* what() const throw() {
    return s.c_str();
}
```

Comment: Please consider not putting `using namespace std` into header files, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice/1452759#1452759

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that you have a constructor initialization list but do not have a well formed constructor definition here:

```
RzymArabException(string ss) : s(ss);
```

If you want to implement the constructor in the `.cpp`, declare it correctly in the header:

```
RzymArabException(string ss);
```

Note that [exception specifications are deprecated](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec), so I have removed them from the code that follows.

Your next problem is that the member definitions all need to be in the `RzymArabException` scope:

```
//RzymArabException.cpp

RzymArabException::RzymArabException(string ss) : s(ss) {}

RzymArabException::~RzymArabException() {}

const char* RzymArabException::what() const {
    return s.c_str();
}
```